I am unable to execute any commands or code
When I run commands like flutter run, flutter clean, flutter doctor in the Visual Studio terminal, I receive the error \flutter\bin\cache was unexpected at this time. Also, when I try to run my code, it asks me to select a device but does not show any devices. Why?
i tried so many things but i didn't
